# Where do documentation stylesheets live?

Tags: stylesheet, workbench

I started using Workbench to write documentation again after some time off.  Something must have happened (maybe upgrading to v12?), because now when I double click on a documentation page in Workbench to edit it, Mathematica beeps on startup.

`Why the Beep?` reports

> The shared stylesheet "Wolfram/FunctionPageStyles.nb" could not be
>   found. The default stylesheet will be used instead.

I found the required stylesheets available for download [here](https://github.com/jfultz/WolframDocViewer/tree/master/Stylesheets).  Where should I put them?

Comment: Have you tried the menu File > Install...?

Comment: System stylesheets live in `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "StyleSheets"}]` and subdirectories.  Local ones should go in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "StyleSheets"}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `File > Install...` didn't help, but putting them in `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Wolfram"}]` manually did.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the original Wolfram Workbench, or the Eclipse plug-in?  I started using the WolframWorkbench (v2 or v3, I don't remember) but that seems deprecated in favor of an Eclipse plugin.  Just a thought that if you are using one of the older Workbench versions, you might want to look into the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: @MarkR Thanks, I should have added that I'm using the latest Eclipse plugin.  Hasn't been that long of a pause!